# Can SQL Server arbitrate between two schemas based on the user or user's role?

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, database-schema

Sql Server 2008 R2

I have a view named the same in two schemas. Can I automatically get an application to use one or the other when it calls stored procedures that reference the view depending on the user or user's role?

e.g. The two views are named dbo.Customers and production.Customers. Each view produces the same select list but have joins to different tables and have different WHERE criteria. Stored procedures currently reference dbo.Customers.

(Note: There are actually dozens of these two-schema views and they are used in hundreds of stored procedures, functions and dynamically generated sql. Rewriting all that would take years)

Answer (score 0):

Object names inside stored procedures (modules) are [resolved based on the owner of the stored procedure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/04/03/567660.aspx) (module) not the executing user. Thus if you reference a table called TABLE_1 inside a stored procedure declared as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_GetTable_1 AS SELECT * FROM [TABLE_1]
```

Then the resolved table name will be [dbo].[TABLE_1].

If you are willing to live with dynamic SQL then you can do something like this:

```
--Stored procedure uses dynamic SQL so object name resolution rules inside
--modules does not apply
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_GetTable_1 AS 
  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM [TABLE_1]'
GO

--create Table_1 in two schemas
CREATE TABLE [Com1].[Table_1](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Schema] As OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME ( OBJECT_ID('[Com1].[Table_1]' ))
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
CREATE TABLE [Com2].[Table_1](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Schema] As OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME ( OBJECT_ID('[Com2].[Table_1]' ))
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

--Now create two users, defaulting each to one of the schemas
CREATE USER Com1User WITHOUT LOGIN WITH default_schema = [Com1]
CREATE USER Com2User WITHOUT LOGIN WITH default_schema = [Com2]

--set the ownership of the schemas to match
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::[Com1] TO [Com1User]
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::[Com2] TO [Com2User]

--Adding the users to the db_owner role naively allows executing dbo schema modules
--for demo purposes. Alternatively grant execution to specific dbo modules 
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'Com1User'
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'Com2User'

--Set the execution context and call the procedure
EXECUTE AS User = 'Com1User'
EXEC dbo.usp_GetTable_1
REVERT;

--Set the execution context and call the procedure
EXECUTE AS User = 'Com2User'
EXEC dbo.usp_GetTable_1
REVERT;
```

Personally, I'm not a big fan of this use of schemas. Schemas are for security and to a lesser extent -- avoiding name collisions for large numbers of database objects. I personally prefer putting each set of objects on a different database and using different user logins with default databases to control the name resolution.